# Audio Glitch Plugin

Tags: pro-tools, logic-pro, plug-in, glitch

I'm looking for a plugin that can create audio glitches on a recording (i.e. clicks, pops, static, clipping, etc.)

I'd like to have some direct control over when and how they happen but random would be ok too.  I'm mainly on Pro Tools 10 OSX but have access to Logic as well.
Thanks!

Update: Just rediscovered a hilarious plugin called Cohmpost which seems to do some of what I need.  Still open to (less silly) alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Illformed.org have a bunch of glitch plug-ins available. you could also look at Izotope Vinyl which was recently re-released as a free plug-in for some vintage clicks, pops and warmth.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u just cut like 0.5 second chuncks in specific places... you could even cut only the bass and let it *click* like a bad edit or something..

You could even use a distortion plugin or an EQ plugin(with some bad setting) with some on/off automation..

There's no real reason to ruin it with a plugin like that

Answer (score 0):

Out of all the Glitch plugins I have used, My top 2 most recommended would be:

- db Blue Glitch
- Image-Line Gross Beat

You can also check this page for a list of glitch plugins, you might want to check this out:

http://www.learnproducing.com/best-glitch-vst-plugins-for-music-producers/

For what you're after, you may want to also look into 
''VinylSound – Free Vinyl Noise VSTi Plugin Released By Rancorsoft''

http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2013/08/26/free-vinyl-vst/